# How to Wrap a Python 'With' Function and Reuse It Somewhere Else

Tags: python, with-statement

Basically I have a Python `With` function that does a site login. Everything else I do needs to fall under a `With` function, so I can continue having the site connection.

As you guessed, I have multiple functions that needing to start with a `With` function. It gets really redundant. But if I just do a normal function wrap, I would lose the site connection.

I need to figure out a way to proper wrap a `With` function.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. It's the Python decorator I'm looking for.

```
def authenticate(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_url = kwargs.get('site_url', '')
        with self.sign_in(MY_TOKEN):
            # initiate server details here
            f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then in my actual function that need the `With` first, I do:

```
@authenticate
def my_func(site_url=''):
    # details of my_func
```

Be aware `site_url` is my keyword argument.